# Finding sentiment of sentence containing not word

Tags: nlp, sentiment-analysis

I used a code for getting **sentiment** (sense i.e good, bad, average) of any **sentence** by matching the adjective word with my predefined set of good, bad, average words, Set of bad words, set of average words in the sentence. But for negation(sentence containing "not") I am not able to assign exact sense(whether good or bad or average) to the sentence containing not from my code.

Ex:- sentence-" Bob is best boy in the school." Since in this sentence there is one adjective "best" matching to the good set than Good sense is assigned to this sentence.

But, for negation sentence-"Bob is not best boy in the school". Since in this sentence there is only one adjective **"best"** matching to the good set than Good sense is assigned to this sentence. But here "not" makes the sense to bad but my code is not able to do handle **"not"** in the sentence.

Help me to solve the negation problem

Comment: One thing i would come up with is search for a number of `not` words in front of you sentiment words (up to the previous one) and negate your original word by the amount of `not` words encountered. Of course, a very simple solution but this might already fit your needs.

Comment: What does this have to do with Java?

Answer (score 0):

"not" is a word to negate expressions in language. To use the term of "negation" would be better for the problem.

To handle "negation", one would use negation triggers (e.g. not, never) and their scopes in sentences. In "Bob is not best boy in the school" example, "best boy in the school" is scope of "not". Scope of negation could be detected via some basic rules or via heuristics using syntactic parse trees as well.

For sentiment analysis, if a sentiment-laden term passes in scope of a negation trigger, one can invert or dampen sentiment value of the trigger or flag the sentiment-laden term.

The case you mentioned is something to be investigated different, however. A superlative adjective in scope of negation may be investigated with adjective's antonym:

```
worst - bad - neutral - good - best
```

So these terms are "scaled" and negation conveys semantics this way:

- "not best" implies one of "worst - bad - neutral - good", however in general between bad and good also other context of the sentence must be examined
- "not good" implies one of "bad - neutral"

This concept is something that I took from Grace's scalar implicature. You can look that up for more detail.

In conclusion for a simple solution, if you use sentiment association scores for those kind of adjectives (e.g. best: *+4*) I suggest not to invert its score directly by multiplying with *-1* when its under scope of negation, but multiplying it with *-0.5* to find in between association.

Hope that helps, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The approach you are taking for "sentiment analysis" is very basic. You need to use some good algorithms for sentiment analysis, a good starting point  is support vector machine, random forests which can give you good results without having huge training data. If you care about very good accuracy, then use deep neural nets. Some of the good option for datasets are mentioned Below.

```
Huge ngrams dataset from google storage.googleapis.com/books/ngrams/books/datasetsv2.html
http://www.sananalytics.com/lab/twitter-sentiment/
http://inclass.kaggle.com/c/si650winter11/data
http://nlp.stanford.edu/sentiment/treebank.html
```

Because of the problem you are facing, people started using statistics for NLP. There are several other steps which are involved before you apply these algorithms like sentence tokenization, word tokenization, lexical analysis etc.